# Import a zipped csv file into Talend

Tags: csv, zip, talend, talend-mdm

Is it possible to import a zipped csv file directly into Talend Open Studio for Big Data 6.3.0.2, if not would there be any work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but in two steps.

Step 1. In the file management section of the components is a `tFileUnarchive` component.  You can use this by first placing a `tFileList` component and connecting it to the `tFileUnarchive` with the iterate connector.

Step 2. The unzipped files will be moved to an output directory you specify.  You can then use another `tFileList` to read those files in, within the same job.

If you find Talend moves quicker than the unzipping process or files are locked you can put in a `tSleep` and wait a few seconds or minutes.  I use the `tSleep` in cases where we need a pause in processing to allow system resources to catch up with the job.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, thank you E LaRoche!  I had a bit of trouble because my files were initially .7z but once I converted to .zip it worked fine

Comment: glad it worked.  That interesting about 7-zip though, because we tested compression with 7-zip, winzip, and native windows zip, and they all worked.  perhaps its the version of Talend or 7-zip.  We are on Talend 6.2.1 and 7-zip 16.04.

Comment: I used 7-zip to compress the file, just had to compress it as a .zip.  I am using Talend v6.3.0 and 7-Zip 16.04